# Display TextView as ImageView to enable zooming

Tags: android

I have a TextView which contains dynamic text (of varying length). In order to enable smooth pinch and zoom, I would like to convert this TextView to an ImageView and display that ImageView instead of the TextView. So I tried to set up the TextView programmcially like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_view);

    String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(SongbookListFragment.SONG_TEXT_ARGS);

    song_textview = new AppCompatTextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    song_textview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    song_textview.setPadding(PADDING,PADDING,PADDING,PADDING);
    song_textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    song_textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    song_textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    song_textview.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    song_textview.setTextSize(16);
}
```

My song_view.xml uses the zoomable PhotoView which extends ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_songtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Now in `onWindowFocusChanged` method of the activity, I convert the TextView to a Bitmap and display it within the PhotoView like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    int width = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
    int height = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
    Bitmap bitmapHolder = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmapHolder);
    if (song_textview != null) {
        song_textview.layout(0, 0, width, height);
        song_textview.draw(c);
        PhotoView songPhotoView = findViewById(R.id.imageview_songtext);
        songPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmapHolder);
    }
}
```

This works well except that I do not know how to set the **height of the Bitmap** within `onWindowFocusChanged`. If I use `this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight()` like in my code sample above, the length of the text is cut because `this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight()` returns the screen height and not the actual height of the TextView. Of course, the TextView is not added to the layout which is why there is no measured height. So how can I get the full length of the TextView to display it in my Bitmap?

Comment: use `song_textview.getHeight()` will work for you

Comment: why?? whay not to zoom the `TextView` itself?

Comment: @pskink: Because I don't want the text to wrap. I want the layout of the text lines to remain the same when zooming.

Comment: it will be the same - you will get no text wrapping

Comment: @pskink: Can you provide an example?